# Need tabular guidance

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabularray, tabulary

I'm a new and learning LaTeX on my own, but I'm finding a lot of different ways to format tables. I hate the code I have below and am hoping there's a better option with something I've just not seen yet.

Overleaf had a tabular example that looked really great, but didn't work with my four column model. I'm very likely not doing something correctly, but I need help finding the right direction to go in.

How do I know which version of tabular will do what I need?

I need:

- Automatic spacing so longer text sizes itself to the cell and goes to the new line. The third column will be continuously changing information, so I can't have cells that need hard returns added manually. This document will be extremely long and creating \makecells like below is going to be extremely tedious.
- The first two columns need to be centered, the next two are left oriented.
- I need step numbering in the first column, so I need some kind of automatic enumeration? maybe?
- I need the table to fit to the size of the page (like `\textwidth`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{9.5cm}|p{6cm}|}
    \hline
    \thead{Step} & \thead{System} & \thead{Detail} & \thead{Expected Results} \\
    \hline
    \makecell[c]{1} & \makecell[c]{DSU} & \makecell[l]{Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.\\ \\ \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.} & Command window opens.\\
    \hline
    \makecell[c]{1} & \makecell[c]{DSU} & \makecell[l]{Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.\\ \\ \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.} & Command window opens.\\
    \hline
    \makecell[c]{1} & \makecell[c]{DSU} & \makecell[l]{Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.\\ \\ \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.} & Command window opens.\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{End section procedure.}}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: You should get rid of most of the `\makecell`s. They destroy the table layout. And the 9.5cm+6cm+2 c columns + intercolumn space is wider than your paper.

Comment: Ugh, yeah I know. I hate them, but at the time it was the only way I could find that did what I wanted consistently. Ultimately, seeing all the work that went into those stupid \makecells is what prompted me to ask the question here. Thank you for your response though! I'll definitely be researching this today and using a lot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth, colspec={|c|c|X[3,l,m]|X[2,l,m]|},
      row{1}={c,font=\bfseries}}
    \hline
    {Step} & {System} & {Detail} & {Expected Results} \\
    \hline
    {1} & {DSU} & {Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.\\[2ex]  \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.} & Command window opens.\\
    \hline
    {1} & {DSU} & {Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.\\[2ex]  \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.} & Command window opens.\\
    \hline
    {1} & {DSU} & {Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.\\[2ex]  \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.} & Command window opens.\\
    \hline
    \SetCell[c=4]{c}{\textbf{End section procedure.}}&&&\\
    \hline
    \end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Several `{ }` pairs could be removed.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the automatic numbering. Thanks @Zarko.

Comment: That's fine! I've got a lot to learn with this, so I'll be researching a lot of all these responses. I'll likely end up mixing and matching to some extent to get exactly what I need. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for the table. As one of the requests is to make table auto resising to the page width, I loaded `tabularx` and its `X` column-type, which auto adapts width to a remaining available space.

The `m{}` redefined inside `X` (1) adds line breaks if texts are too long, (2) allows adding `\par` (or empty lines) to form multiple paragraphs, and finally (3) applies the middle alignment. Additionally, due to non-zero `\parskip` extra vertical space is added between paragraphs.

There is also a counter, which is automatically iterated per each row by `\stepcounter'.

The table:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}
\newcommand\thead[1]{\normalfont\bfseries #1}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\parskip=9pt\RaggedRight}m{#1}}
\newcounter{nrow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.45}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|
      >{\stepcounter{nrow}}c|c|X|>{\parskip=9pt\RaggedRight}m{3.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \thead{Step} & \thead{System} & \thead{Detail} & \thead{Expected Results} \\
    \hline
    \thenrow & DSU &
      Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.
      \par
      \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.
      & Command window opens. \\
    \hline
    \thenrow & DSU &
      Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.
      
      \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.
      & Command window opens.\\
    \hline
    \thenrow & DSU &
      \kant[1][1]

      \kant[1][2]
      & Command window opens.\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{End section procedure.}} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of @Celdor and @Pieter van Oostrum answers: automatic numbering of steps, use of `tabularray` package with more concise table code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\newlength\cw   % column width
\newcounter{rn} % row number

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \settowidth\cw{\textbf{Expected Results}}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c c X[l,m] Q[l, wd=\cw] },
             cell{2-Y}{1} = {cmd=\stepcounter{rn}\thern},
             row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries}
             }
Step    &   System  &   Detail  &   Expected Results        \\
        &   DSU     &   {Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.\\[2ex]
                        \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.}
                                & Command window opens.     \\
        &   DSU     &   {Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.\\[2ex]
                        \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.}
                                & Command window opens.     \\
        &   DSU     &   {Click \textbf{Start} and type: \textit{cmd} and press \textbf{Enter}.\\[2ex]
                        \textbf{Note}: This may take several minutes.}
                                & Command window opens.     \\
\SetCell[c=4]{c}    \textbf{End section procedure}  & & &   \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great and easy to follow/teach to others. For that counter though, can I alter the specific way it numbers steps? like, if i need it to be 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, can it do that?

Comment: @VGoodWriter, yes, of course: `cell{2-Y}{1} = {cmd=\stepcounter{rn}1.\thern}`.  However, instead of `1.` you can define  new counter, which you increment when is needed (for example in multicolumn cell) .  How to do this, please ask new question, where explain desired scenario of numbering.

Comment: This helps, thank you!

Comment: @VGoodWriter, now you may consider to accept one of received answer (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answers), which you most liked :-)

Comment: Oh, god. It's like The Bachelor, but way less interesting.

Lol, I'm still weighing options, but I'll choose soon!

Comment: Ok! I went with a combination of the responses from Zarko and @Pieter van Oostrum. The only remaining question will be how to reset the step counter at the beginning of each table, but I think I can probably figure that out on my own. 

Thank you both so much! This is so close to what I had before my \makecells that I feel like I'd have ended up here if i'd not gone astray.

Comment: @VGoodWriter, since you select Peter as the best answer for you, you should ask him, how to solve this problem. I cant interfere in his answer ...

Comment: I actually figured it out! I was dreading it, but it was a very simple answer to find and even simpler to implement. Thanks, though!

Comment: @VGoodWriter, again, you not select my answer, so you not need to inform me what you doing with accepted answer. Address this to author of accepted answer.